# pandas - binning data and getting 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very simple dataframe. There are 2 columns, day_created (int, could change to datetime) and suspended (int, could change to boolean). I can change the data if it makes it easier to work with.

```
       Day created  Suspended
0               12          0
1                6          1
2               24          0
3                8          0
4              100          1
5               30          0
6                1          1
7                6          0
```

The day_created column is the integer of the day the account was created (from a start date), starting at 1 and increasing. The suspended column is a 1 for suspension and a 0 for no suspension.

What I would like to do is bin these accounts into groups of 30 days or months, but from each bin get a total number of accounts for that month and the number of accounts suspended that were created in that month. I then plan on creating a bar graph with 2 bars for each month.

How should I go about this? I don't use pandas often. I assume I need to do some tricks with resample and count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
df.index = start_date + pd.to_timedelta(df['Day created'], unit='D')
```

to give the DataFrame an index of Timestamps representing when the accounts were created.

Then you can use

```
result = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).agg(['count', 'sum'])
```

to group the rows of the DataFrame (by months) according to the Timestamps in the index. 
`.agg(['count', 'sum'])` computes the number of accounts (the count) and the number of suspended accounts for each group.

Then `result.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)` plots the bar graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Day created': [12, 6, 24, 8, 100, 30, 1, 6],
     'Suspended': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]})
start_date = pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01')
df.index = start_date + pd.to_timedelta(df['Day created'], unit='D')

result = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))['Suspended'].agg(['count', 'sum'])
result = result.rename(columns={'sum':'suspended'})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
result.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(locs, result.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Comment: I did to dig into the matplotlib docs, but is there a simple way to truncate the hh:mm:ss from the dates?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to use `plt.xticks` to set new xtick labels. I've modified the code above to show what I mean.